# Elements inside Rectangle()'s overlay are not responding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having troubles with understanding what the problem is with my layout. Currently none of the elements like textfield, buttons, and menu that are in popUp are responding. Those elements are located in Rectangles overlay content.

I've tried setting them separately outside the rectangle but no luck. I've also tried changing allowing hit test for different elements but no luck as well. What I've tried is to allow hit test for buttons and textfield with menu. Do you guys have any thoughts on why that might be happening? I appologize if the fix is obviouse, but I just couldn't find it:(

Here is my Main view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Budgets: View {


@EnvironmentObject private var budgetsViewModel: BudgetsViewModel
@Binding var isCustomItemSelected: Bool
@Binding var showAddBudgetBtn: Bool

@State private var animatePopUp: Bool = false

private let fonts = Fonts()

init(isCustomItemSelected: Binding<Bool>, showAddBudgetBtn: Binding<Bool>) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont(name: Fonts().RobotoMedium, size: 18.0)!]
    
    self._isCustomItemSelected = isCustomItemSelected
    self._showAddBudgetBtn = showAddBudgetBtn
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            // VStack containing two ZStacks
            VStack {
                // ZStack at the top
                ZStack {
                    Color("OnboardingBgColor") // Replace with your content
                        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2.38)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                    Button {
                        print("Pressed")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Top ZStack Content") // Replace with your content
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }

                }
                
                // ZStack at the bottom
                ZStack {
                    Color("MainBgColor") // Replace with your content
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    Text("Bottom ZStack Content") // Replace with your content
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }//: VSTACK
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(Color("MainBgColor"))
            
            //MARK: -Present add budget popup
            if isCustomItemSelected {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(15.0)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.195, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3.314)
                        .opacity(animatePopUp ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                        .scaleEffect(animatePopUp ? 1.0 : 0.85)
                        .offset(y: -UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.15)
                        .overlay {
                            VStack {
                                VStack(spacing: 15.0) {
                                    // Title
                                    Text("add.budget.popup.title".localized)
                                        .font(Font.custom(fonts.RobotoMedium, size: 16.0))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    
                                    // Inputs
                                    VStack(spacing: 10) {
                                        budgetNameInput
                                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 52)
                                        
                                        budgetCurrencyMenu
                                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 52)
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.273, height: 120)
                                }
                                .offset(y: 20)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.273, height: 151)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                // Buttons
                                HStack {
                                    AddBudgetButton(style: .cancel) {
                                        // Cancel Button
                                        print("Cancel")
                                        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.4)) {
                                            isCustomItemSelected = false
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 76, height: 33)
                                    .accessibility(label: Text("Cancel Button"))
                                    .allowsHitTesting(true)
                                    
                                    AddBudgetButton(style: .create) {
                                        // Create Button
                                        print("Create")
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 76, height: 33)
                                    .accessibility(label: Text("Create Button"))
                                    .allowsHitTesting(true)
                                }
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.273, height: 33, alignment: .trailing)
                                .offset(y: -15)
                            }
                            .opacity(animatePopUp ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                            .scaleEffect(animatePopUp ? 1.0 : 0.85)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.195, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3.314)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0))
                            .offset(y: -UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.15)
                        }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.35)) {
                        animatePopUp = true
                    }
                })
            }//: ADDBUDGETPOPUP
        }//: ZSTACK
        .onAppear {
            showAddBudgetBtn = true
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("budgets.navbar.title".localized)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .accentColor(.white)
        .toolbar {
            if !isCustomItemSelected {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        print("Edit")
                    } label: {
                        Text("edit.toolbar.nav.trailing".localized)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(Font.custom(fonts.RobotoRegular, size: 15.0))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//: NAVVIEW
}



var budgetNameInput: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 5) {
        Text("add.budget.popup.budget.name".localized)
            .font(Font.custom(fonts.RobotoMedium, size: 11.0))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .background(.clear)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 12, alignment: .leading)
        
        Color("BudgetsAddPopUpInputBg")
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 35)
            .overlay {
                TextField("add.budget.popup.name.example".localized, text: $budgetsViewModel.budget_name)
                    .font(Font.custom(fonts.RobotoRegular, size: 11.0))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289) - 20, height: 35)
                    .accessibilityLabel("Budget Name Input")
            }
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 52)
}

var budgetCurrencyMenu: some View {
    Menu {
        ForEach(budgetsViewModel.currencies_list, id: \.self) { section in
            Text("\(section.symbol) - \(section.name)")
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.white)
    } label: {
        VStack(spacing: 5) {
            Text("add.budget.popup.budget.currency".localized)
                .font(Font.custom(fonts.RobotoMedium, size: 11.0))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .background(.clear)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 12, alignment: .leading)
            
            Color("BudgetsAddPopUpInputBg")
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 35)
                .overlay {
                    Text("$ - USD")
                        .font(Font.custom(fonts.RobotoRegular, size: 11.5))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289) - 20, height: 35, alignment: .leading)
                        .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .background(.clear)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 14))
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .trailing)
                        }
                }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.289, height: 52)
    }
    .pickerStyle(.menu)
}
}
    struct Budgets_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            let showAddBudgetPopup: Bool = true
            StatefulPreviewWrapper(showAddBudgetPopup) { Budgets(isCustomItemSelected: $0, showAddBudgetBtn: $0) }
        }
    }
```

Buttons:

```
import SwiftUI

enum ButtonStyle {
    case create
    case cancel
    case save
}

struct AddBudgetButton: View {


let style: ButtonStyle
let action: () -> Void
let fonts: Fonts = Fonts()

var body: some View {
    
    let title: String
    let buttonColor: Color
    
    switch style {
    case .create:
        buttonColor = Color("OnboardingBgColor") // Use your special color
        title = "add.budget.create.btn".localized
    case .cancel:
        buttonColor = Color("AddBudgetCancelBtn")
        title = "add.budget.cancel.btn".localized
    case .save:
        buttonColor = Color("AddBudgetSaveBtn")
        title = "add.budget.save.btn".localized
    }
    
    return Button(action: action) {
        Text(title)
            .font(Font.custom(fonts.RobotoMedium, size: 12.0))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 76, height: 33)
            .background(buttonColor)
            .cornerRadius(7)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
    .allowsHitTesting(true)
}
}
```

Comment: I put your code in a fresh iOS project and invented all the parts you did not provide and voila: all the AddBudgetButton and the TextField respond (in Simulator).

Comment: I'd suggest using a sheet for your 'add budget popup'. Btw, I would avoid hard coding frame sizes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying it out, turns out that the ZStack that is in isCustomItemSelected conditional was causing the trouble. I will try fidgeting with sheets to meet the expected UI animations:)